# podman: .dockerignore file not excluding socket files

Tags: docker, podman

When I try to build an image I get the error,

```
ERRO[0007] Can't add file /home/ccade/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/dfa9bea029efc1222500f997bf64d37a0eb4800bff3a87e916d3b8aaa213bd3e/diff/var/cache/dnf/grafana-13e251e56a0c8862/pubring/S.gpg-agent to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported
```

I added a .dockerignore file to the build directory. I tried the following entries:

```
S.gpg-agent
*S.gpg-agent
**/S.gpg-agent
*/S.gpg-agent
```

however, the build each time tries to add that file and produces the error. I thought specifying that file name in .dockerignore would mean it got excluded from the build.

Comment: Which podman version? (Maybe you found a bug. You could aslo ask https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions where the Podman developers usually answer questions)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use buildah, maybe your version of podman has a known bug related to .dockerignore.